# Open all Excel Workbooks in folder and copy & paste

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I want to open all Excel workbooks in a folder, one-by-one and copy the cell B1 into the active workbook.
Are the references right?

```
Sub CopyPaste
    Const strVerzeichnis As String = "C:\Users\amke\Desktop"
    Dim StrDatei As String
    Const StrTyp As String = "*.xls"
    Dim Dateiname As String
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Dateiname = Dir(strVerzeichnis & StrTyp)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While Dateiname <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strVerzeichnis & Dateiname

        Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("sheet1").Cells("B1").Copy _
          Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1")
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few fixes:

```vb
Sub CopyPaste
    Const strVerzeichnis As String = "C:\Users\amke\Desktop\" 'Add trailing \
    Dim StrDatei As String
    Const StrTyp As String = "*.xls"
    Dim Dateiname As String, rngPaste As Range
    
    Set rngPaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dateiname = Dir(strVerzeichnis & StrTyp)
    Do While Dateiname <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strVerzeichnis & Dateiname)
            .Worksheets("sheet1").Cells("B1").Copy rngPaste
            Set rngPaste = rngPaste.offset(1, 0) 'next paste location
            .Close False                         'no save
        End with
        Dateiname = Dir() 'next file, if any 
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately it is still not working. The debugger shows me, that the Do While loop is skipped. Therefore I changed the StrTyp to StrTyp="*.csv" Still it is not working, although I have a document in the correct folder. Could you help me please?

Comment: Works for me - any .xls file is directly on my desktop is found.